# rake db:migrate error when i'm trying install ratyrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I tried to  install `ratyrate`. I added it to my `Gemfile` and ran `bundle install`

Now, after running `rake db:migrate`, I got this:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:36: warning: already initialized constant MIME::Type::VERSION
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mime/type.rb:56: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:40: warning: already initialized constant MIME::Type::MEDIA_TYPE_RE
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mime/type.rb:61: warning: previous definition of MEDIA_TYPE_RE was here
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:43: warning: already initialized constant MIME::Type::PLATFORM_RE
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mime/type.rb:64: warning: previous definition of PLATFORM_RE was here
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:50: warning: already initialized constant MIME::Type::IANA_URL
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mime/type.rb:71: warning: previous definition of IANA_URL was here
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MIME::Type::RFC_URL
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mime/type.rb:72: warning: previous definition of RFC_URL was here
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:52: warning: already initialized constant MIME::Type::DRAFT_URL
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mime/type.rb:73: warning: previous definition of DRAFT_URL was here
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:54: warning: already initialized constant MIME::Type::CONTACT_URL
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mime/type.rb:74: warning: previous definition of CONTACT_URL was here
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'paperclip'.
/home/ilyakogan/project1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ilyakogan/project1/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/ilyakogan/project1/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
NameError: private constant MIME::Type::MEDIA_TYPE_RE referenced
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:738:in `singleton class'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:721:in `<class:Types>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:562:in `<module:MIME>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.2.1/lib/paperclip.rb:62:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.2.1/lib/paperclip.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ilyakogan/project1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ilyakogan/project1/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/ilyakogan/project1/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `mime-type` gem seems to be available in 2 different directories:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-1.25.1/lib/mime/types.rb:40: warning: already initialized constant MIME::Type::MEDIA_TYPE_RE
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mime/type.rb:61: warning: previous definition of MEDIA_TYPE_RE was here
```

So, you have to uninstall the gem under `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/`.